# Issue with image not showing up

Tags: html, css

I am currently following a guide on coursera. But im stuck at a part where my image in my localhost server is not showing up. So its making it to where I cannot continue on with the course. specifically the image for the nav bar. Here is a link to my git.

https://github.com/leoisking/Chinese-Restaurant.git

Comment: Have you checked the url you are giving for the location of that background image?

Comment: Yes the path is correct.

Comment: Is it a proper URL (as opposed to just the local file path)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display image use `img` element.

```
<img src="img_girl.jpg" alt="Logo image" width="500" height="600">
```

Where `src` is your image path.

For refereance see below link.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp

Comment: Would this still allow me to have the image inside the navbar area?

Comment: Yes you can use `img` inside nav. Use img element instead of id="logo-img" div.

Comment: Ok I will try that out